# R: How to order boxplots by variance?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Is it possible to order box plots in R by their variance?

```
rm(list = ls())
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

data(airquality)
airquality$Month <- factor(airquality$Month,
                           labels = c("May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"))


p10 <- ggplot(airquality, aes(x = Month, y = Ozone)) +
        geom_boxplot()
p10
```

[image: Box-Plot]

How can I make it so that the variable with the most variation would be on the left of this plot?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `reorder` you could do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data(airquality)
airquality$Month <- factor(airquality$Month,
                           labels = c("May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"))


ggplot(airquality, aes(x = reorder(Month, Ozone, function(x) -var(x, na.rm = TRUE)), y = Ozone)) +
  geom_boxplot()
#> Warning: Removed 37 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full tidyverse-based reprex

```r
library(tidyverse)

airquality %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  mutate(var = var(Ozone, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Month = fct_reorder(month.abb[Month], -var)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Ozone)) +
  geom_boxplot()
#> Warning: Removed 37 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>